# How to stop Spring Integration application?

Tags: spring-integration

Is it a standard good way to stop a SI application?
I mean I don't want in progress processes to be killed while workflows are running etc.

Thanks,

Ferenc

Answer (score 0):

Actually it doesn't matter if your application uses SI, Spring Batch, Boot or is it just raw Spring one, all in-progress processes are finished correctly, if you use normal application shutdown - `System.exit(0)`. In this the `ApplicationContext` is finished with its `close()` and initiate `stop()` for all `Lifecycle` components.

To avoid message loosing you should consider to use persistent `MessageStore` for `<queue>` channels and transactions or something similar like `acknowledges` in messaging Brokers like JMS, AMQP etc.

Comment: Also see [Orderly Shutown Managed Operation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#jmx-mbean-shutdown).

Comment: Hi Gary, the link has been broken

Comment: This is an actual link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management.html#jmx-shutdown